# How do I install Parallels Guest Tools on Maverick?

Tags: 10.10, virtualization

I'm trying out Maverick in a Parallels 6 VM, and running into some trouble with the installation script for the Guest Tools:

```
Start installation or upgrade of Guest Tools
Installed Guest Tools were not found
Perform installation into the /usr/lib/parallels-tools directory
cat: /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/../version: No such file or directory
Start installation of prl_eth kernel module
make: Entering directory `/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods'
cd prl_eth/pvmnet && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/build M=/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-22-generic'
  LD      /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/pvmnet.o
  LD [M]  /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/prl_eth.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: modpost: missing MODULE_LICENSE() in /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/prl_eth.o
see include/linux/module.h for more information
  CC      /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/prl_eth.mod.o
  LD [M]  /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet/prl_eth.ko
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-22-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_eth/pvmnet'
cd prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/build SUBDIRS=/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg SRCROOT=/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-22-generic'
  CC [M]  /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/prltg.o
  LD [M]  /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/prl_tg.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: modpost: missing MODULE_LICENSE() in /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/prl_tg.o
see include/linux/module.h for more information
WARNING: modpost: Found 3 section mismatch(es).
To see full details build your kernel with:
'make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y'
  CC      /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/prl_tg.mod.o
  LD [M]  /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/prl_tg.ko
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-22-generic'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg'
cp -f prl_tg/Toolgate/Guest/Linux/prl_tg/*.symvers prl_fs/SharedFolders/Guest/Linux/prl_fs ||:
cd prl_fs/SharedFolders/Guest/Linux/prl_fs && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_fs/SharedFolders/Guest/Linux/prl_fs'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/build M=/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_fs/SharedFolders/Guest/Linux/prl_fs
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-22-generic'
  LD      /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_fs/SharedFolders/Guest/Linux/prl_fs/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_fs/SharedFolders/Guest/Linux/prl_fs/super.o
  CC [M]  /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_fs/SharedFolders/Guest/Linux/prl_fs/inode.o
  CC [M]  /usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_fs/SharedFolders/Guest/Linux/prl_fs/file.o
/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_fs/SharedFolders/Guest/Linux/prl_fs/file.c:389: error: ‘simple_sync_file’ undeclared here (not in a function)
make[3]: *** [/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_fs/SharedFolders/Guest/Linux/prl_fs/file.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_fs/SharedFolders/Guest/Linux/prl_fs] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.35-22-generic'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods/prl_fs/SharedFolders/Guest/Linux/prl_fs'
make: *** [all] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/parallels-tools/kmods'
Error: could not build kernel modules
Error: failed to install kernel modules
2010-10-11T20:49:47-0500: execCmd: ./install --install [143]
2010-10-11T20:49:47-0500: Error: An error occurred when installing Parallels Tools. Please go to /var/log/parallels-tools-install.log for more information.
```

Has anyone successfully got this to install? Is there something I can fix on my end, or do I have to wait for Parallels to support it?

Comment: I've logged a support request with Parallels regarding this. If they give me a workaround I will post it here.

Comment: Parallels is just giving me the runaround. No word on when this will be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the following update to resolve this problem:

http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v6/en_us/parallels/ga/ParallelsDesktop-parallels-en_US-6.0.11826.611899.dmg

Why this took three days of back-and-forth with their email support to pry this url from them is beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the Parallels Guest Tools' kernel modules do not support Linux 2.6.35 yet. Can you download a newer version of the tools? If not, you'll have some source code editing to do. (I don't have Parallels, so this is the full extent of the advice I can give. :-P)

Comment: That's correct. I still have to use the 2.6.18 kernel (with patches) in order to utilize Parallels Guest Tools

Comment: @Marco: 2.6.18?! That's as bad as Xen back in the bad ol' pre-pvops days! Thanks for sharing your experiences. +1

Comment: There may be newer accepted Kernel versions. However for internal development servers we tend not to go crazy with upgrades.